# Calling other VB projects from my current project

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have created a notepad, a Tic Tac Toe and a scientific calculator. All these are in different projects.

Now, I am creating another project. It will Have three buttons, one for calculator, one for tic tac toe, and one for notepad. On clicking any of the buttons, the respective project should run.

For example, if a user clicks on notepad, then the notepad project should start execution and the user should be able to use notepad. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each of your projects in a standalone exe, you can do [something like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

```
    Dim myProcess As New Process()
    Dim myProcessStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(path_to_exe), "spawn")
    myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo
    myProcess.Start()
```